# How can I sort a list of maps by value of some specific key using Java 8?

Tags: java, sorting, java-8

How can I sort a `List` of `Map<String, String>` using Java 8? The map contains a key called `last_name`, and the value associated with it may be `null`. I'm not sure how to do it because the following results in a compiler error:

```
List<Map<String, String>> peopleList = ...

peopleList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Map::get, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

Is using an anonymous class the only way to do it?

Note that I am **not** trying to sort each map in the list. I want to sort the list itself based on a key in each map.

Comment: How can you sort  without specifying the field last_name

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Might have to sort the old fashioned way using an anonymous class.

Comment: @Pshemo Even if they weren't `Object`, how do you go about comparing two `Map<String,String>`s? There's a reason maps don't implement `Comparable`.

Comment: Yes, @Pshemo. I just want to compare against one specific key, and list the maps in order in the list by that key.

Comment: In that case you can just replace `Map::get` with more specific `m->m.get("yourKey")`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you can rewrite your code like

```
peopleList.sort(
    Comparator.comparing(
        m -> m.get("yourKey"),  //what property should be compared
        Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()) //how it should be compared
    )
)
```

Comment: Now I think this is the best answer, the nulls are handled perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Since your `peopleList` might contain a `null` and the `Map::key` might have a null value, you probably need to `nullsLast` twice:

```
peopleList.sort(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(m -> m.get("last_name"),
                            Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))));
```

Comment: I think you should remove the first `Comparator.nullsLast`

Answer (score 3):

This should fit your requirement.

```
peopleList.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.get("last_name").compareTo(o2.get("last_name")));
```

In case you want handle the null pointer try this "old fashion" solution:

```
peopleList.sort((o1, o2) ->
{
  String v1 = o1.get("last_name");
  String v2 = o2.get("last_name");
  return (v1 == v2) ? 0 : (v1 == null ? 1 : (v2 == null ? -1 : v1.compareTo(v2))) ;
});
```

Switch `1` and `-1` if you want the `null` values first or last.

For thoroughness' sake I've added the generator of useful test cases:

```
Random random = new Random();

random.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());

IntStream.range(0, random.nextInt(20)).forEach(i -> {
  Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
  String name = new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(6);
  if (random.nextBoolean())
    name = null;
  map1.put("last_name", name);
  peopleList.add(map1);
});
```

Comment: @BJPeterDeLaCruz `getOrDefault("last_name", "")` works only if map has no `last_name` key. If map contains such key and it holds `null` value then that `null` value will be returned instead of `""`.

Comment: @Eugene, there are many maps in the list, and the maps contain many keys, including `last_name`.

Comment: That comparator attempting to handle `null` is inconsistent, hence, broken. It always returns `-1` if the first argument maps to `null`, not considering that the second could also map to `null`. On the other hand, if the first maps to an empty string and the second maps to `null`, it will return `0` indicating equality, etc. By the way, what’s the point of the `.map(Function.identity())` step?

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your analysis, and I know, is not "beautiful" :) I've tested the solution and is not broken. The `Function.identity()` stands for `a -> a` lambda. I've just rewritten again the solution in a more readable (and old fashion) way.

Comment: You “tested” the solution by running it with a particular input where the inconsistency happened to cause no harm. This doesn’t change the fact that this comparator violates the contract in several ways, and may (and will) break with other inputs. Besides that, I know what `Function.identity()` does; it doesn’t matter whether you write `.map(Function.identity())` or `.map(v2 -> v2)`, both implies a mapping step that doesn’t do anything, thus, is just obsolete.

Comment: @Holger I think you've not tested the code, but without the part `o2Nullable.map(v2 -> v2).orElse("")` a NPE can be raised.

Comment: @Holger Arghh... you were right, when tried with 1000 different cases a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!` has been raised! Please :) Could you explain how did you get that the comparator were inconsistent?

Comment: Well, as said, check what happens, if both, `v1` and `v2`, are `null`. The result obviously should be `0`, as these are equal, but formally, not returning `0` (like `1` in your oldfashioned comparator) will violate the constraint that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` has to hold for all `x` and `y`. Your `Optional` based solution had the additional issue of mapping the second argument to an empty string if `null` via `.orElse("")`, which it didn’t do for the first argument, so it’s obvious that this can’t be symmetric.

Comment: As a final note, `o2Nullable.map(v2 -> v2).orElse("")` should never produce a different outcome than `o2Nullable.orElse("")`.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the explanation, I like delve deeper into this matter. BTW I've fixed the "old fashion" comparator following your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can override de compare method of the Collection.
Here is an example: 
https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-lambda-comparator-example/

You will have to compare the last_name of the objects, and do not forget to handle the null properly.

Answer (score -2):

```
Steps to sort a Map in Java 8.

1]Convert a Map into a Stream
2]Sort it
3]Collect and return a new LinkedHashMap (keep the order)

Map result = map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
    (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: Incidentally, if the OP *did* want to sort a map, I think `Map<..., ...> result = new TreeMap<>(map)` would be a better approach.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

By Keys:

```
Map<String, String> result = unsortMap.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
    (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

By Values:

```
 Map<String, String> result = unsortMap.entrySet().stream()
.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
(oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```